# Find index of array to remove item in to do list

Tags: javascript

with local storage I've made a simple to do list which can add and save items. I'm wanting to remove items when the 'removeButton' is clicked, but I'm not sure how to get the index of the list item so I can use 'array.splice' to remove the item from the 'toDoArray'.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1bj8mfp/3/

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>to do</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="itemValue" type="text" placeholder="Add item">
            <button id="addItem" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
        </form>
        <ul id="to-do-list"></ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javacript**

```
// Add item
var toDo = function(){
    var itemValueData = document.getElementById('itemValue').value;
    var valueData = new values(itemValueData);

    // Push items
    toDoArray.push(valueData);

    // Local storage
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(toDoArray));

    // Remove button
    var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.classList.add('to-do-remove');
    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove";

    // Print out items
    var listContainer = document.createElement('li');
    listContainer.innerHTML = itemValueData;
    listContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
    toDoList.appendChild(listContainer);

    // Remove item
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}

addItem.addEventListener("click", toDo);

// Remove item
var removeItem = function(){

};
```

Comment: `index = (number of previous siblings of <this.parentNode>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `previousSibling` as the comment says, you cannot use `indexOf` on a DOM Node(which is not an "array-ish" instance)

```
// Remove item
var removeItem = function(e){
  var li = e.target.parentNode

  // get index
  var index = 0
  while (li.previousSibling) {
    li = li.previousSibling
    index++
  }

  toDoArr.splice(index, 1)
};
```

Personally, i would suggest you to go with `Array.prototype.filter` instead of `Array.prototype.splice`, like so:

```
// Remove item
var removeItem = function(e){
  var li = e.target.parentNode
  var text = li.firstChild.wholeText

  todoArr = toDoArr.filter(todo => todo !== text)
};
```

As Todo app is very famous in JS front-end community for providing structured way to compare various single page MV* frameworks, you might get more insights by looking into the community efforts: [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/)

Comment: Cheers mate will take a look! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. When building each item, you can capture the array indices in closures
2. If adding and removing cause a complete re-build, your indicies will always be correct

If you can use ES6, I would re-write this as a class and then tie that class to the DOM.

```
class ToDo {
    constructor(ul) {
        this.items = [];
        this.container = ul;
        this.load();
    }
    build() {
        // empty container (slice is to get around live NodeList)
        const children = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.container.childNodes);
        children.forEach(child => {
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        });
        // re-build list inside container
        this.items.forEach((item, i) => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));

            const remove = document.createElement('button');
            remove.appendChild(document.createTextNode('remove'));
            remove.addEventListener('click', e => this.remove(i));

            li.appendChild(remove);

            this.container.appendChild(li);
        });
    }
    load() {
        const json = localStorage.getItem('todos') || '[]';
        this.items.length = 0; // same ref lives on!
        this.items.push(...JSON.parse(json));
        this.build();
    }
    save() {
        const json = JSON.stringify(this.items);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', json);
    }
    add(val) {
        this.items.push(val);
        this.save();
        this.build();
    }
    remove(i) {
        this.items.splice(i, 1);
        this.save();
        this.build();
    }
}
```

And then tie to DOM

```
const container = document.getElementById('to-do-list');
const toDo = new ToDo(container);
document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const val = document.getElementById('itemValue').value;
    toDo.add(val);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dngkbw5w/1/)